# How to migrate TFS site collection from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2019?

Tags: sharepoint-server

Can anyone help with the best approach how to migrate site collection and documents from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2019?
It is urgent. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Three main options:

1. database migration - move the content databases to SP 2016, mount them, back them up, move the backups to the 2019 farm, and mount them there. MS has this process fully documented, as usually you'll need to migrate the databases for a few service apps as well.
2. use a tool. There are a number of tools, ShareGate is one. These tools are usually not cheap, but they save a lot of time vs the next method for anything other than small environments.
3. manual migration: in 2019 create new site collections / libraries as needed. Open both the 2013 and 2019 libraries in explorer view, and copy files from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

What version of TFS are you using? It may not support SharePoint integration in the future as per Microsoft's article at [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sharepoint-dashboards/about-sharepoint-integration?view=tfs-2018)

Answer (score 0):

We are using TFS 2015, but there also wiki site on that site collecetion and lot of documents. We need to provide versioning on 2019 site, which will be probably team site.